# How to fix: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, arraylist

I encountered a problem when I tried to run the following code:

```
ArrayList paretoSet=new ArrayList();   // contains a collection of ArrayList
ArrayList<Integer> toPass=new ArrayList<Integer>();
int[] fParetoSet=new int[ParetoSet.size()];
int[] gParetoSet=new int[ParetoSet.size()];

for (int i=0;i<paretoSet.size();i++){
        toPass.clear();
        toPass.add((Integer)paretoSet.get(i));
        int [] totake=calculate(toPass);
        fParetoSet[i]=totake[0];
        gParetoSet[i]=totake[1];       
    }
```

`
where claculate(ArrayList x) is a method that takes an integer arraylist and returns an integer array. I can not make Paretoset an integer arraylist as it creates problem in other parts of my program. I encountered an exception in the line             **toPass.add((Integer)paretoSet.get(i));**
as *java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer*
  How should I fix this problem?
  Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, please use Java coding conventions.  `PareToSet` should start with a lower case letter;  I thought you were calling a static method at first.

Comment: You haven't shown us what goes _into_ `ParetoSet`. I assume it's `ArrayList`s, but show us to confirm.

Comment: So the type of ParetoSet is `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, correct?

Comment: ((Integer)ParetoSet.get(i)), you cast a arraylist to int. toPass.add(ParetoSet.get(i)) may be what you want.

Comment: are you sure you are getting an error? Because I just copy paste and  run your code. It works without any issues. One more thing you don't have to cast ParetoSet.size() to Integer

Comment: I agree paretoSet ,being a variable should be in lower case. I have improved it. paretoSet is a collection of arraylists as mentioned in the code. For  eg. 

> paretoset=[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [2,6,3]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ParetoSet` is a collection of `ArrayList`, then the call `ParetoSet.get(i)` will return the `ArrayList` at index `i`. As the error says, an `ArrayList` is not a a type of `Integer` and cannot be cast to one.

Other points of interest:

- your variable should be camel case: `pareToSet`
- auto-boxing means the cast in your for loop has been unnecessary since JDK5
- `Paretoset` has been declared with a raw type
- type inference makes `new ArrayList<Integer>()` redundant since JDK7

**EDIT**

- your variable should be camel case: `paretoSet`, as per Jim's comments

**EDIT**

An ArrayList is neither conceptually, or actually an Integer. If you say the sentence 'A list is a type of integer' it doesn't make sense. If we check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for ArrayList we can see that its inheritance tree is:

```
java.lang.Object
java.util.AbstractCollection<E>
java.util.AbstractList<E>
java.util.ArrayList<E>

All Implemented Interfaces:
Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, List<E>, RandomAccess
```

So we can say for example that `ArrayList` is a type of `AbstractList`, or `AbstractCollection`, but not an `Integer` as `Integer` is not part of its lineage.

Comment: Yes, you got it correctly but this is what my program requires. I need to pass an arraylist of integer type to method calculate() and I can not make paretoSet an integer arraylist as it creates problem in other methods of the program. Is there any other way of doing that?

Comment: You are missing the point, `toPass` is an `ArrayList` of `Integer` and can, presumably, be passed to your `calculate()` method. Your problem is that you have said that `toPass` can only accept `Integer`s and then you are trying to add an `ArrayList` to it.

Comment: If this answers your question, then please accept it

Comment: Please note that I tried to add *(Integer)paretoSet.get(i)* to *toPass*  and this is where the problem occurs. I tried to cast an arraylist at index i in *paretoSet* to integer type and then added it to *toPass*  but this casting is not allowed!!!   and my problem remains as it is.

Answer (score 0):

your program having typecasting issue on below lines.
your are trying to add typecast list of arraylist to Integer arryalist. this wrong. if you want add the arraylist objects to some other arryalist. Please use generics as object.

```
ArrayList ParetoSet=new ArrayList();   // contains a collection of ArrayList
toPass.add((Integer)ParetoSet.get(i));
```

This should be like below:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> ParetoSet=new ArrayList<ArrayList>();  
ArrayList<ArrayList> toPass=new ArrayList<ArrayList>();  
toPass.add(ParetoSet.get(i));
```

Then you should  change code bit to fit your further your logics

Comment: Please put complete code as what you are trying to achieve as sample program and I may try to find the real issue..